# R - Recoding column with multiple text values associated with one code

Tags: r, case-sensitive, stringr, recode

I'm trying to recode a column to determine the shift of an employee.

The data is messy and the word I am looking for must be extracted from the text. I've been trying various routes with `if` statements, `stringr` and `dplyr` packages, but can't figure out how to get them to work together.

I have this line of code, but str_match doesn't produce a true/false value.

```
Data$Shift <- if(str_match(Data$Unit, regex(first, ignore_case = TRUE))) {
    print("First Shift")
  } else {
    print("Lame")
  }
```

recode is working, but I have multiple values I need to recode and want to learn if there is a way to incorperate stringr into the recode function.

```
Data$Shift1 <- recode(Data$Unit, "1st" = "First Shift")
```

Currently, the text must be extracted from the column to contain 1st, First, or first for First Shift. My data looks like the Unit Column, and I want to Recode it into the Shift Column:

```
Unit                        Shift
Detention, Third Shift      Third Shift
D, 3rd Shift                Third Shift
1st                         First Shift
first shift                 First Shift
First Shift                 First Shift
1st shift                   First Shift
1st Shifft                  First Shift `
```

Comment: If you are putting a value into Data$shift, you don't want to use `print`. You should also use `ifelse` not `if` here. `stringr` is probably overkill, why not just a few statements like `Data$shift[grepl("3rd", Data$shift)] <- "Third Shift"`?

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Just went from 100 unique values to 6.

Comment: Just FYI, `str_match` doesn't return a true/false, but `str_detect` does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend just using `grepl` with `case_when` within `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  mutate(Shift = case_when(grepl("first|1st", Unit, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "First Shift",
                           grepl("third|3rd", Unit, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ "Third Shift",
                           TRUE                                         ~ "Neither"))
```

- `mutate` creates our new column `Shift`
- `grepl` returns a logical vector if it matches the pattern or not.  In this case, the pattern I used was `"first|1st"`.  The `|` character means OR, so as is, that checks for either "first" OR "1st".
- `case_when` works like multiple "if" statements, allowing us to keep our logic together (similar to SQL syntax).  The final line of `case_when` is kind of our safety net here....if a value for `Unit` does not contain 1st or 3rd shift, it will return "Neither", and so we know to investigate further.

If you don't have a recent version of `dplyr` (>`0.7.3`), then `case_when` might not work for you.  If so, we can replace `case_when` with a chain of nested `ifelse`.

```
Data %>% 
  mutate(Shift = ifelse(grepl("first|1st", Unit, ignore.case = TRUE),
                        "First Shift",
                        ifelse(grepl("third|3rd", Unit, ignore.case = TRUE),
                               "Third Shift",
                               "Neither")))
```

Not as pretty, but should be the same result since our patterns used in `grepl` are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried running it, but for some reason, it's not reading my column where "Unit" is unless Data$Unit is specified. When fixed, it runs without error, but does not produce the Shift column. The package is installed. Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: Oh, this might be an issue with the package version of `dplyr` you are using.  `packageVersion("dplyr")` for me is `0.7.4`.  I believe `case_when` was made available in version `0.7.3`.  Also, is `Data` a dataframe?

Comment: Okay that's probably it. I have 0.5.0, even after update.packages    Data is a data.frame

Comment: I'll add an option for older `dplyr` versions

Comment: Thank you! For whatever reason, I had to add 'Data1 = ' before the above section to include the new column in a new dataset, but it's working perfect otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
Data$shift[grepl("3rd", Data$shift)] <- "Third Shift"
Data$shift[grepl("1st", Data$shift)] <- "First Shift"
```

Etc.