# dplyr::recode in conjunction with stringr::str_detect()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I am trying to recode a character variable with `dplyr::recode()` and `stringr::str_detect()`. I realize that this can be done with `dplyr::case_when()`, as documented here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/recoding-using-str-detect/5141, but I am convinced that there has to be a way of doing it via `recode()`.

Consider this case:

```
library(tidyverse)
rm(list = ls())

data <- tribble(
  ~id, ~time,
  #--|--|
  1, "a",
  2, "b",
  3, "x"
)
```

I would like to replace the "x" in the dataframe with a "c" via `str_detect()` and here's how I'd do it:

```
data %>% 
 mutate(time = recode(data$time, str_detect(data$time, "x") = "c"))
```

But that doesn't work:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   "data %>% 
>     mutate(time = recode(data$time, str_detect(data$time, "x") ="

Apparently R doesn't know what to do with the last `=`, but I believe it has to be there for the recode function, as demonstrated here:

```
recode(data$time, "x" = "c")
```

This executes properly, as does this:

```
str_detect(data$time, "x")
```

But this does not:

```
recode(data$time, str_detect(data$time, "x") = "c")
```

Is there a way of getting these two functions to work with each other?

Comment: `str_detect` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not the character you are looking for. Either use `gsub` or if you want to use `str_detect`, `case_when` or `ifelse`.

Comment: So that is the problem. `recode()` does not understand what to do with `TRUE` instead of the actual character, I see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want as simple as possible for this, I'd use `gsub`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(time = gsub("x", "c", time))
```

That eliminates the use of `recode` and `str_detect`

If you're dead set on using `stringr`, then you should use `str_replace` rather than `str_detect`:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(time = str_replace(time, "x", "c"))
```

If you want to replace the entire value if it contains an 'x', then just add some regex:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(time = str_replace(time, ".*x.*", "c"))
```

Breakdown of the regex: `.*` represents any character (except \n) matching at least 0 times.  We put `.*` both in front and behind the x, so that way if there are any leading or trailing characters from the 'x', they are still captured.

Comment: this is unfortunately not an option, as I need str_detect to target and replace certain observations in my actual data.

Comment: see my edits if you want to use `stringr`.  `str_detect` just does not feel appropriate for your case.  But to be honest, you just described `gsub` with your comment

Comment: I have a hunch you might be doing the same coursework as this question asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49632442/6535514

Comment: like `gsub`, `str_replace` only replaces the string that I tell it to look for and leaves eventual trailing characters intact. this is not what I am looking for, hence the need for `str_detect`. it seems like `case_when` really is the only appropriate solution for this purpose.

>edit: interesting coincidence, but I'm trying to recode a time variable into an ordered factor with this. I'll stick to `case_when` for that purpose

Comment: Oh, then you just need to modify your pattern to include more specific regex.  As is, your original question just said you wanted to chance 'x' to 'c'

Comment: and there we have it! This seems to work as intended, but ultimately `case_when` has proven to be the best solution to this, for the reasons @phiver pointed out.